# Angular 2 inserting json data using http

Tags: angular, angular2-services

```
http://localhost:3000/userinfo
[
  {
    "username": "simon",
    "password": "password1"
  },
  {
    "username": "bala",
    "password": "password2"
  },
  {
    "username": "prabha",
    "password": "password3"
  }
]
```

myservice.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class MyserviceService {
  constructor(private _http:Http) { }
  addData(){
    let data2=JSON.stringify({"username":"asir","password":"007" });
    let headers=new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/userinfo',data2,options)
      .map((res:Response) =>res.json());
    }
}
```

loginregister.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Forlogin } from 'app/forlogin';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms'; 
import { MyserviceService } from 'app/myservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loginregister',
  templateUrl: './loginregister.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loginregister.component.css'],
})
export class LoginregisterComponent implements OnInit {
    postdata:string;
    url='http://localhost:3000/userinfo';
  constructor(private myservice:MyserviceService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
onPostData(){
this.myservice.addData().subscribe(
    data => this.postdata=data
    );console.log("result"+this.postdata);
}
}
```

loginregister.html

```
{{postdata}}
```

I like to add content to `http://localhost:3000/userinfo` using post method. This code does not works and returns "unidentified: 500 error". I need to find out whats wrong with this code. pls solve the issue guys.
Please provide suggestions as to why data isn't getting written to the file..

errormsg shows like that:

```
ERROR Object{  
   _body:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id…",
   status:500,
   ok:false,
   statusText:"Internal Server Error",
   headers:Object,
   type:2,
   url:"http://localhost:3000/userinfo"
}
```

Comment: status 500 is a server error. you should take a look at the backend logs. your code should probably be fine.

Comment: onPostData(){
this.myservice.addData().subscribe(
    data => this.postdata=data
    );console.log("result"+this.postdata);
}
} is that method correct bro?

Comment: i am using json-server for json data

Comment: @simonasir  this is a server error, plz check your api and db query or linq level logic

Comment: ok bro i ll check it..

Comment: Another hint for future discussions: the amount of people that like to be addressed as "bro" is probably quite low on Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: okay matt i ll definitely stop saying like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is simple we should pass id inorder to post data into json-server like this,
let data2=JSON.stringify({**"id":1**,"username":"asir","password":"007" });